# Serverless plugin or yaml feature to merge defaults into a serverless file?

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework

I have a serverless file with:

```
custom:
  specificProp: true
```

I have another file with a property that should be shared by multiple serverless files:

```
custom:
  commonProp: true
```

Is there any Serverless plugin or yaml feature that would allow me to merge the file with the common prop into the first file to produce:

```
custom:
  specificProp: true
  commonProp: true
```